# Why is checkbox onclick function not working?

Tags: javascript, html

Im building a flask app, but I cant figure out how to get the onclick event for the checkboxes to work. The function *toggleAlarm* should trigger a request but I'm not receiving anything.
The click event for the button is working fine tough.

'''

{% for alarm in alarms %}
 {{ alarm.time }} {{alarm.days}}

```
  <button type="button" id="alarm-delete" class="close" onClick=deleteAlarm({{ alarm.id | safe }})>
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <label>
    {% if alarm.state == 1 %}
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{ alarm.id }}" onClick=toggleAlarm({{ alarm.id | safe }}) checked>  
    {% else %}
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{ alarm.id }}" onClick=toggleAlarm({{ alarm.id | safe }})> 
    {% endif %}
  </label>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quotes for the `onclick` attribute.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{ alarm.id }}" onClick=toggleAlarm({{ alarm.id | safe }})>
```

Should be

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{ alarm.id }}" onclick="toggleAlarm({{ alarm.id | safe }});">
```

It's not required but you should also do `onclick` instead of `onClick` as that's the proper attribute camelCase name